# Event lost from argo event bus if sensor is unable to trigger a workflow due to some x.y.z reason

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argo-workflows, argo

We are using NATS as our eventBus impl and noticed one issue where our msgs got missed from the eventbus with no error or alerts from ARGO :-

Let's say we are using a sqs trigger to trigger our workflows, the whole flow is below:-

```
1) a web app publishes a msg to a SQS.
2) SQS event source polls the msg from sqs, put it into event-bus and delete the msg from SQS.
3) sensor polls the msg from event-bus and try to hit a workflow trigger but somehow fails to trigger the workflow(even it fails to start the k8s pod for the workflow).
4) Due to step 3, we have lost the polled msg with no error,alert etc.
```

My question is how we can make this thing resillient i.e how to configure sensor so that msg can only be deleted from the event-bus iff workflow has been triggered and if not how to run some alternate light-weight failover workflow?